# useTransition does take into account if the callback is expensive in time or browser is busy doing layout computations?

Tags: reactjs

I'm developing an app for smart tvs that are very limited in CPU resources. I am trying to use useTransition hook to don't block the main JS thread with react render and to pause react render and throttle to be able to not freeze or jank the page, since the FPS are very low. Is this possible?